Show that differentiability implies continuity but not vice versa.
Given the differentiability of the function we have
\begin{equation}
    f'(z_{0})=\lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}
\end{equation}
So:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \to z_{0}} f(z) &= \lim_{z \to z_{0}} (f(z)+f(z_{0})-f(z_{0}))\\
&=f(z_{0})+\lim_{z \to z_{0}} (f(z)-f(z_{0})) \\
&=f(z_{0})+ \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \left( \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0}}{z-z_{0}} (z-z_{0}) \right) \quad \text{if $z \neq z_{0}$}\\
&=f(z_{0})+\lim_{z \to z_{0}} \left( \frac{f(z)-f(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}  \right) \cdot \lim_{z \to z_{0}} (z-z_{0}) \quad \text{def.}\\
&=f(z_{0})+f'(z) \cdot 0 \\
&= f(z_{0})
\end{align*}
It seems that this proof is adequate, I think. Now, what counterexample outside of the functions involving the module, may be curious?
Thanks!!!

Your implication is written backwards since it starts with an assertion that the limit equals something before you know the limit exists. For the converse all you need is one counterexample. Most are likely just variants on $|x|$.

Any continuous but not diferentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be used to generate a counterexample

@EthanBolker I don't understand your point very well, I start from the differentiability of the function, or can you tell me how to express it better? I would be grateful.

$x \sin (\frac 1 x)$ is continuous but not differentiable at $0$.

Ethan Bolker's suggestion of $|x|$ is easier. You didn't start with differentiability. You started with $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(x)$ and go through several formulas before on the fourth line you finally bring in the assumption of differentiability. These formulas assume the limits involved exist. Consider what happens if $f(x) = \sin(1/x), x \ne 0; f(0) = 0$. The first three equations are false before you even get to differentiability. (Of couse $f'(0)$ doesn't exist - I am showing the flaw in your proof, not claiming the theorem is false.)

And the flaw is just in how you stated it. The idea you are using is correct, and if you hold off on taking the limit until you are ready to bring in differentiability to show it exists, you will be good. It even gives you a reason for requiring $z \ne z_0$, which your version doesn't have, since $z$ is only dummy variable in it, and the definition of limit already discounts the case of $z = z_0$.
